# MVC Checkboxlist for Losing Values on Postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkboxlist

I am having below CheckboxListFor which is displaying the values. When postback, I am getting the values which I checked.

When model state in invalid, I am returning the view but I am losing the values and the checkboxes which I checked get unchecked. How can I do this ?

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(m => m.Features.FeaturesIds, 
                  m => m.AvailableFeatures, 
                  m => m.Id, 
                  m => m.Name, 
                  m => m.SelectedFeatures)
```

Below is the POST method code related to the checkboxlist

```
var itemAttributes =  itemRepository.GetAvailableAttributes(1, ItemLevel.Item)
                .Where(i => i.AttributeTypeId == (int)AttributeTypeEnum.PropertyCheckbox);
        var itemAttrsAndValues = itemAttributes.Select(attr => new AttributeChecked(attr)).ToList();
        model.Features = itemAttrsAndValues;
```

Comment: What is `CheckboxListFor()` Is this your own implementation or a plugin you have downloaded?

Comment: @StephenMuecke http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/613785/How-to-Use-CheckBoxListFor-With-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Show your POST method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Its a very big one. Did you need any part of code ?

Comment: No POST method should be more than a dozen lines, but post it and I'll delete anything that irrelevant